# rclone mount webdav whenever a certain application is started

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, automounting, hook

I'd like to automatically mount a nextcloud directory (webdav) with my keepass-database in it using `rclone` whenever I start KeepassXC and unmount it after closing Keepass. Is there any way to do this (Maybe some kind of hook-functionality?)

I know that I could create a systemd service to mount the directory at startup, but I like the idea of not having it mounted all the time.

Any help and hints are appreciated (it's an Arch Linux System).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that a batch or bash script with

Something like:

```
rclone connect  ... &&
keepassXC
rclone disconnect ...
```

In windows you could just make a shortcut to it.  In linux make it executable, throw the script in the path and make a desktop item for it.

Thanks for pointing out rclone, it solves a dropbox connection problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after Ted pointed me to the right direction.
Here is the script that does what I want.

```
#!/bin/bash
rclone mount pw: ~/.pws/ --vfs-cache-mode full & 
/usr/bin/keepassxc && 
fusermount -u ~/.pws/
```

Put it into /usr/local/bin to get it found before the keepassxc executable in /usr/bin and that's it.